# Rendering to next Screen failed in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, render

I have a college project to make game about smasher game with LibGDX, and i made it so that when the player life is 0, it switch to EndGameScreen class from the GameScreen class, but this happens
[failed render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrzvT.jpg), I'm actually not sure if it's because of the setScreen method or my EndGameScreen class is not right

> GameScreen Class

```
//setScreen in GameScreen 
if (life == 0) { //this is inside the render function
        game.setScreen(game.endGame);
        dispose();
    }
@Override
public void dispose() {
    bg.dispose();
    fontScore.dispose();
    lifes.get(0).dispose();
    lifes.get(1).dispose();
    lifes.get(2).dispose();
    bactery0Arr.clear();
    bactery1Arr.clear();
    bactery2Arr.clear();
}
```

> EndGameScreen Class

```
//EndGameScreen class
public class EndGameScreen implements Screen {
final BacterySmasher game;
OrthographicCamera camera;

public EndGameScreen(final BacterySmasher game) {
    this.game = game;

    //Set camera
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 1280, 720);
}

@Override
public void show() {

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    camera.update();
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    game.batch.begin();
    game.batch.draw(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bg.png")), 0,0,0,0);
    game.batch.end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling `dispose()` in the render method of `GameScreen`? Instead call when the screen is hidden.

```
   @Override
    public void hide() {
        dispose();
    }
```

Comment: I moved it to the hide() function, but It still doesn't work. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I won't put down another answer but this line ```game.batch.draw(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bg.png")), 0,0,0,0);``` maybe sets the size of the rendered image 0 width and 0 height and so effectively nothing is drawn over the last screen (which is disposed). If ```batch``` is ```spritebatch```.